# Correctly Assigning Variables of a Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I would like to correctly set the types for the Comparable objects. I have the following method:

```
abstract <T> boolean check( Comparable<T> first, T second );
```

For now, the parameters first and second are declared as follows:

```
 Comparable first = convertStringValueToType(attribute.getValue(), attribute.getType());
 Comparable second = convertStringValueToType(expectedValue.getFirst(), attribute.getType());
```

The method `convertStringValueToType()` returns either a String, BigDecimal, or Boolean. Unfortunately I cannot just use `attribute.getType()`  as that returns another object (DataElementAttributeType).

I **think** that `first` should be `Comparable<?> first` as we don't know what type we will get. However, if I make it `Comparable<?>` then that means `second` should be `?` as well. I'm not sure how I can make `second` be of type `?` as `?` is not a type.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

**Edit:** `first` and `second` are compared inside `check()` using `first.compareTo(second)`. We will always be comparing the same types (String to String, boolean to boolean, etc.) as `second` is given from a configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in a type-safe way, because just because two objects are both `Comparable`s doesn't mean they can compare to each other. You are getting objects which might be one of several different `Comparable` types (and you will only know which at runtime), and there is no commonality about what they can compare to; e.g. `String` can only compare to `String`s, whereas `BigDecimal` can only compare to `BigDecimal`s, so all you can say is that the object can compare to "something" (i.e. `Comparable<?>`), which is completely useless for compile-time type checking purposes.

You will only know whether one can compare to the other by running `.compareTo()` and seeing whether it produces a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't need both objects to be `Comparable`s. `first` should be a `Comparable<T>` while `second` is just type `T`. And it can be assumed that `first` and `second` are comparable as this is enforced through configuration files where the values are set.

Comment: @Abubakr: Generics are a compile-time construct. It is not useful for type-checking if the types cannot be known at compile-time. You are saying, I don't need type checking because the user will use the right types. Well, if that's the case, then you don't need generics. `first.compareTo(second)` should compile successfully the way you have currently declared them (with an unchecked call warning).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just wanted to know if it is was possible.

Answer (score -1):

For that you have to extend the `Comparable`

```
    String x = "sdf", x2 = "sdf";
    int y = 55, y2 = 56;
    Boolean ob = true, ob2 = false;
    Compare compare = new Compare();
    compare.check(y2, y2);
    compare.check(ob, ob2);
    compare.check(x, x);

//For your case it will be
  Compare compare = new Compare();
  compare.check(convertStringValueToType(attribute.getValue(), attribute.getType()), convertStringValueToType(expectedValue.getFirst(), attribute.getType()));

class Compare<T extends Comparable> {

int check(T first, T second) {
    return first.compareTo(second);
}
}
```

Comment: Does that still have the same behavior? We would like for first and second to always be comparable using compareTo().

Comment: They need to be comparable to each other, like in `first.compareTo(second)`?

Comment: Also, because you do not know what exact Object is being returned like `Comparable<String>` vs `Comparable<BigDecimal>`, it doesn't really make sense for your check method to be so specific.

Comment: How do you compare Boolean and BigDecimal  or BigDecimal   and String

Comment: The value for `second` is passed in through a configuration file and we assume that first and second are comparable and are the same type. (Meaning that we will always compare boolean and boolean, BigDecimal and BigDecimal, or String and String). We are comparing them to each using first.compareTo(second).

Comment: What do you mean that we do not need the check method to be very specific?

Comment: Is this still the same as the original? In the original `first` is of type `Comparable<T>` and `second` is of type `T`. However, in this case both `first` and `second` are of type `T extends Comparable`.

Comment: Yeah anyhow you want to compare both objects right.the both objects should be of `Comparable` then only you can use `compareTo`.That's why the change